# Extracting the signature of "invokables"

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a problem extracting the signatures of functions, member functions and lambdas. I have written the code below to do it, but I'd like a metafunction to do the same, if one is possible. The problem with the existing solution is, that lambdas cannot be a template parameters.

```
template <typename R, typename ...A>
struct signature
{
};

template <typename R, typename ...A>
constexpr auto num_args(signature<R, A...> const)
{
    return sizeof...(A);
}

template <typename R, typename ...A>
constexpr auto extract_signature() noexcept
{
  return signature<R, A...>();
};

template <typename C, typename R, typename ...A>
constexpr auto extract_signature(R (C::* const)(A...)) noexcept
{
  return extract_signature<R, A...>();
}

template <typename C, typename R, typename ...A>
constexpr auto extract_signature(R (C::* const)(A...) const) noexcept
{
  return extract_signature<R, A...>();
}

template <typename R, typename ...A>
constexpr auto extract_signature(R (*const)(A...)) noexcept
{
  return extract_signature<R, A...>();
}

template <typename F>
constexpr auto extract_signature(F const& f) noexcept ->
  decltype(&F::operator(), extract_signature(&F::operator()))
{
  return extract_signature(&F::operator());
}

template <typename F>
constexpr auto extract_signature(F const& f) noexcept ->
  decltype(f(), extract_signature(f))
{
  return extract_signature(f);
}
```

I am looking for something like:

```
template <???>
struct signature_info
{
  using type = signature<R, A...>;
};
```

The metafunction should extract `R` and `A...` somehow, if possible, through perhaps a `decltype(lambda)`?

EDIT:

```
::std::cout << ::std::integral_constant<::std::size_t, num_args(extract_signature([](int, int, int){}))>{} << ::std::endl;
```

Will produce an error:

```
t.cpp:54:85: error: a lambda expression may not appear inside of a constant expression
  ::std::cout << ::std::integral_constant<::std::size_t, num_args(extract_signature([](int, int, int){}))>{} << ::std::endl;
                                                                                    ^
t.cpp:54:58: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
  ::std::cout << ::std::integral_constant<::std::size_t, num_args(extract_signature([](int, int, int){}))>{} << ::std::endl;
                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
t.cpp:54:85: note: non-literal type '(lambda at t.cpp:54:85)' cannot be used in a constant expression
  ::std::cout << ::std::integral_constant<::std::size_t, num_args(extract_signature([](int, int, int){}))>{} << ::std::endl;
```

Comment: "The problem with the existing solution is, that lambdas cannot be a template parameters." -- While the lambda syntax cannot appear in a template argument, given any existing lambda such as `auto lambda = [](){};`, `extract_signature(lambda)` is perfectly valid. Or at least, will be once you take out your last overload that introduces infinite recursion.

Comment: What case does the last `extract_signature` handle (the one with `decltype(f(), extract_signature(f))`)?

Comment: @Niall function pointer, after decay.

Comment: Looks like you might want `sizeof...(A..)` to get the count of the arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the last listed code snippet.

This could be done in a similar fashion to how `std::function<>` works...

```
template <typename S>
struct signature_info

template <typename R, typename A...>
struct signature_info<R(A...)>
{
  using type = signature<R, A...>;
  static const std::size_t count = sizeof...(A);
};
```

The above specialisation can be extended to support all the function types you wish to support.

For example, for a simple `const` member function;

```
template <typename C, typename R, typename... A>
struct signature_info<R(C::*)(A...) const>
{
  using type = signature<R, A...>;
  static const std::size_t count = sizeof...(A);
};
```

To get the count of the arguments `A...`, you can use `sizeof...(A..)`.

With a meta function...

```
template <typename R, typename ...A>
struct signature
{
};

template <typename S>
struct signature_info;

template <typename R, typename... A>
struct signature_info<R(A...)>
{
  using type = signature<R, A...>;
};

template <typename S>
signature_info<S> get_signature()
{
    return signature_info<S>{};
}

void func(int);

int main()
{
    auto abc = get_signature<decltype(func)>();
    cout << abc.count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

A full working sample of the combined OP code (with recursion removed) and the code above [can be found here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1076365ba7bf9d6b).

---

Given the code snippet and compiler error - lambdas cannot be used where `constexpr` (core constant expression) is required (although there are proposed changes in this regard).

The code can be modified to the following for compilation to succeed;

```
auto lambda = [](int, int, int){};
std::cout << ::std::integral_constant<::std::size_t, decltype(extract_signature(lambda))::count>{} << ::std::endl;
```

With a full [working sample here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fa8ee9a2861a80b);

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;
template <typename R, typename ...A>
struct signature
{
  static const std::size_t count = sizeof...(A);
};

template <typename R, typename ...A>
constexpr auto extract_signature1() noexcept
{
  return signature<R, A...>();
}

template <typename C, typename R, typename ...A>
constexpr auto extract_signature2(R (C::* const)(A...)) noexcept
{
  return extract_signature1<R, A...>();
}

template <typename C, typename R, typename ...A>
constexpr auto extract_signature2(R (C::* const)(A...) const) noexcept
{
  return extract_signature1<R, A...>();
}

template <typename R, typename ...A>
constexpr auto extract_signature(R (*const)(A...)) noexcept
{
  return extract_signature1<R, A...>();
}

template <typename F>
constexpr auto extract_signature(F const& f) noexcept ->
  decltype(&F::operator(), extract_signature2(&F::operator()))
{
  return extract_signature2(&F::operator());
}

int main()
{
    auto lambda = [](int, int, int){};
    std::cout << ::std::integral_constant<::std::size_t, decltype(extract_signature(lambda))::count>{} << ::std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I had deduction in mind. Can a metafunction deduce?

Comment: Sure, the trick would be to get the `operator()` for the lambda; bear in mind that the type for the lambda is a class with the call operator.

Comment: @user1095108. I've updated the code with a working example (modified, but based on your code) for the compilation error you are getting.